# シャッフルパズルゲームのシャッフルについて

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

pythonを使い、数字を順番通りにならべかえるゲームを作っています。terminalで表示して遊べるところまではできたのですが、ソースコードにも書いている`random.shuffle(list1)`を使ってしまうと、本当に数字がランダムにシャッフルされてしまい、元どおりにならべかえることが難しくなってしまうゲームになっています。
現在、

```
123
456
78
```

と右下に１マス空け、上下左右ランダムに10回ほど動いてからゲームを開始するというプログラムを書きたいのですが、これをどうやればいいか悩んでいます。
教えていただけると幸いです。

```
import string
import random
import sys
moves = 0
game_start=True 
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
random.shuffle(list1)
print('\n'*2)

matrix33=[]
while list1 !=[]:
    matrix33.append(list1[:3])
    list1 = list1[3:]

def zero(board):
    global empty_space
    for x in range (len(board)):
        for y in range(len(board[x])):
            if board[x][y]==0:
                empty_space = (x,y)
    return empty_space

def draw_board(board):
    print('\n\t+-----+-----+-----|')
    for x in range (len(board)):
        for y in range(len(board[x])):
            if board[x][y] == 0:
                print('\t|  XX' , end='')
            else:
                print('\t|  ' + '{:02d}' .format(board[x][y]), end=' ') 
        print('\n\t+-------+-------+-------|')

def ask_number():
    global num , piece 
    num = input('\nplease type the number of the piece to move : ( q ) to quit  ')
    if num in ['q','Q']:
        print('\n\ngame over  ')
        sys.exit()     
    num = int(num)
    piece=()
    for i in range(len(matrix33)):
        for j in range(len(matrix33[i])):
            if num == matrix33[i][j]:
                piece = (i,j)
    return piece , num

zero(matrix33)
while game_start:
    draw_board(matrix33)      
    ask_number()         
    if num > 8:
        print('illegal move , try again  ')
    else:
        if(empty_space==(piece[0]-1,piece[1]))\
           or(empty_space==(piece[0]+1,piece[1]))\
           or(empty_space==(piece[0],piece[1]-1))\
           or(empty_space==(piece[0],piece[1]+1)):
            matrix33[empty_space[0]][empty_space[1]]=num
            matrix33[piece[0]][piece[1]]=0
            empty_space=(piece[0],piece[1])
            moves = moves +1
            print()
            print('you have made ',moves , 'moves so far ')
            print(2*'\n')
        else:
            print('illegal move , try again ')
```

Comment: いわゆる[8パズル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/15%E3%83%91%E3%82%BA%E3%83%AB)ですね！　本文のド頭にパズルの説明があるとご質問の内容が読みやすくなりそうです :)　「数字を並び替えるゲーム」だと色々あるので……。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

質問文のソースコードには「与えられた方向にコマを動かす」という部分の処理が既にあるので、ここを関数化した上で、「与えられた方向」をランダムに決めてコマを動かす処理を10回繰り返せば良さそうです。もちろんそのままだと動かせない場合があるので、動かせた場合だけ数えるようにします。

具体的には、ちょっと雑ですがたとえば下のように書けます。

```py
matrix33 = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
empty_space = (0, 0)
dir = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]]

# matrix33[y][x] にあるコマを空白へ移動する関数。
# 移動できたら True、できなかったら False を返す。
def move(y, x):
    global empty_space, matrix33
    if x < 0 or x > 2 or y < 0 or y > 2:
        print('x and y should be between 0 and 2')
        sys.exit(1)

    # 動かせるかチェックする
    can_move = False
    for i in range(4):
        target = (y + dir[i][0], x + dir[i][1])
        if target == empty_space:
            can_move = True
            break
    if not can_move:
        return False

    # 動かす
    num = matrix33[y][x]
    matrix33[empty_space[0]][empty_space[1]] = num
    matrix33[y][x] = 0
    empty_space = (y, x)
    return True

# n回シャッフルする関数。
def shuffle():
    count = 0
    while count < n:
        x = random.randint(0, 2)
        y = random.randint(0, 2)
        ok = move(y, x)
        if ok:
            count = count + 1

shuffle(10)
```

このように `move` 関数として機能を切り出すと、プレイヤーにコマを動かしてもらうところも下のように簡潔になります。

```py
if move(piece[0], piece[1]):
    moves = moves + 1
    print()
    print('you have made ', moves, 'moves so far.')
    print(2*'\n')
else:
    print('illegal move, try again.')
```

以下おまけです。

- 最初は `shuffle` 関数の引数として小さめの数を渡すとデバッグしやすいです。
- もっと Python っぽく書くにはクラスを使いたいところですね。
- ところで今のソースコードだと8パズルの1手を決める際「○番のコマを空白へ動かす」と考えていますが、逆に「空白部分を×方向に動かす」と考えることもできます。8パズルくらいだと前者の考え方でもシャッフルはたいてい高速に終わるので問題ありませんが、コマの数が増えてくると後者の方が「動かせない」状態に陥る確率が低く、シャッフルがすぐ終わるようになります。

Comment: shuffleを含めて試してみたのですが、このshuffleはどのように書けば反映されるのでしょうか

Comment: 動作例をWandboxに置いてみました: https://wandbox.org/permlink/NXYbpGAgQOFbLC2n

Answer (score 2):

８パズルの駒は偶奇性があって、ルール通りの動かし方をする限り偶数パリティな状態から奇数パリティな状態には絶対にならないことが証明されています。

別言語ですが参照。
[８パズルで、最初にシャッフルさせる時の考え方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/)